# WordPress : Password Protected Page (2)

Tags: php, wordpress, password-protection

I just upgraded my site to a new version WordPress 3.9.2. I noticed that one of my page is not working the way it usually does. This page is password protected and I made changes on how it looks. When I upgraded, it doesn't work anymore. In the password protected page, I have this code:

```
<?php
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>\nwindow.location = 'http://www.google.com'</script>";
?>
```

The purpose of that one is to redirect to another page. And they go hand in hand with this code below.
Here is my old code:

```
    <?php
function my_password_form() {
    global $post;
    $label = 'pwbox-'.( empty( $post->ID ) ? rand() : $post->ID );
    $o = '<form action="' . get_option('siteurl') . '/wp-pass.php" method="post">
    ' . __( "To view this protected post, enter the password below:" ) . '
    <label for="' . $label . '">' . __( "Password:" ) . ' </label><input name="post_password" id="' . $label . '" type="password" size="20" maxlength="20" /><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="' . esc_attr__( "Submit" ) . '" />
    </form>
    ';
    return $o;
}
add_filter( 'the_password_form', 'my_password_form' );
?>
```

Before the upgrade, after inputting the password it redirects me to another page, which is how I wanted it to work. But take note of the action attribute of form. In the WP 3.9.2, wp-pass.php does not exist anymore so I was looking for another code. I saw this line:

```
action="' . esc_url( site_url( 'wp-login.php?action=postpass', 'login_post' ) ) . '"
```

But after inputting the password, it redirects me to the wp-login which is not what I wanted. I need help with this, which works the same way with the old code I'm using. I am not going to downgrade my WP or install any plugin. I just want the value of the `action=""` changed. Thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason you only upgraded to 3.9.2, rather than 4.0?

Comment: Because I wanted to use 3.9.2. Even if I upgraded to 4.0, there is still no wp-pass.php.

Comment: If you look at the [changelog for Version 3.4](http://codex.wordpress.org/Version_3.4), you'll see the following: `Set post password cookies via an action in wp-login.php; retire wp-pass.php (one less root file); obey login ssl preferences for post password form submission`. Hope this helps a bit. You'll need to hook into **wp-login.php** now.

Comment: but different users are going to input the same password. I can't redirect them to the wp-login page because they don't need to go there.

Comment: It has nothing to do with redirecting to `/wp-login`. **wp-login.php** is in the `/includes` folder of WordPress, and is used to handle user authentication.

Comment: I don't have a wp-login.php in my wp-admin/includes nor /wp-includes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already found the answer. Maybe my files weren't compatible that's why it didn't work but here is the full code.

```
<?php
    function my_password_form() {
        global $post;
        $label = 'pwbox-'.( empty( $post->ID ) ? rand() : $post->ID );
        $o = '<form action="' . get_option('siteurl') . '/wp-login.php?action=postpass" method="post">
        ' . __( "To view this protected post, enter the password below:" ) . '
        <label for="' . $label . '">' . __( "Password:" ) . ' </label><input name="post_password" id="' . $label . '" type="password" size="20" maxlength="20" /><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="' . esc_attr__( "Submit" ) . '" />
        </form>
        ';
        return $o;
    }
    add_filter( 'the_password_form', 'my_password_form' );
    ?>
```

**NOTE :**  *I am using WordPress 3.9.2*

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and i found a solution

1) Set your page private with a password

2) Insert this form in an other page (typique postpass wordpress form) :

```
<form action="https://exemple.com/wp-login.php?action=postpass" class="post-password-form" method="post" id="go-pro-espace">
     <input name="post_password" id="exemple" type="password" size="20" /><br />
     <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

3) Change your /wp-login.php file (root directory, at this time, this is located line 460) :

```
from:
wp_safe_redirect( wp_get_referer() );
to:
wp_safe_redirect( "https://exemple.fr/your-protected-page" );
```

Take a look to the answer: [Wordpress protected page, POST form on a other page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44906073/wordpress-protected-page-post-form-on-a-other-page/44923769#44923769)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.